# ekg-core/GHC RTS : bogus GC stats when running on Google Cloud Run

Tags: haskell, ghc, google-cloud-run, hypervisor

I have two services deployed on Google cloud infrastructure; Service 1 runs on Compute Engine and Service 2 on Cloud Run and I'd like to log their memory usage via the `ekg-core` library (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ekg-core-0.1.1.7/docs/System-Metrics.html).

The logging bracket is similar to this :

```
mems <- newStore
registerGcMetrics mems
void $ concurrently io (loop mems)
where
  loop ms = do
    m <- sampleAll ms
    ... (lookup the gauges from m and log their values)
    threadDelay dt
    loop ms
```

I'm very puzzled by this: both `rts.gc.current_bytes_used` and `rts.gc.max_bytes_used` gauges return constant 0 in the case of Service 2 (the Cloud Run one), even though I'm using the same sampling/logging functionality and build options for both services. I should add that the concurrent process in `concurrently` is a web server, and I expect the base memory load to be around 200 KB, not 0B.

This is about where my knowledge ends; could this behaviour be due to the Google Cloud Run hypervisor ("gVisor") implementing certain syscalls in a non-standard way (gVisor syscall guide : https://gvisor.dev/docs/user_guide/compatibility/linux/amd64/) ?

Thank you for any pointers to guides/manuals/computer wisdom.

Details :

Both are built with these options :

`-optl-pthread -optc-Os -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N -with-rtsopts=-T`

the only difference is that Service 2 has an additional flag `-with-rtsopts=-M2G` since Cloud Run services must work with 2 GB of memory at most.
The container OS in both cases is Debian 10.4 ("Buster").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking a bit longer about this, this behaviour is perfectly reasonable in the "serverless" model; resources(both CPU and memory) are throttled down to 0 when the service is not processing requests [1], which is exactly what ekg picks up.

Why logs are printed out even outside of requests is still a bit of a mystery, though ..

[1] https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#lifecycle